# Change Java version in Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have JDK-11 In my system. Can I use more than JDK-11 in the Maven project? If yes then how? I have tested but got the error:

[image]

Comment: eclipse has its own compiler.

Comment: What Eclipse version do you have? What is the error message (see _Problems_ view)? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the version you want to use in Maven should be installed in your system. However, if there is another project in your system which uses java 11 and consequently you do not want to uninstall java 11, there are ways to install multiple versions of java in a system.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better use the version you download or got bug

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: oh "or got bug"? What's that even mean.